# VB.Net assign values to datatable

Tags: vb.net

Hi I have the String and integers to which some values are assigned. now i need to read the string and integer values and assigned them to the datatable which i have created using VB.Net..

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then 
For n As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1 
EmployeeNo = (dt.Rows(n)(0)) 
EmpName = (dt.Rows(n)(1)).ToString 
Commission = CDbl(dt.Rows(n)(2)) 
'I need to read one by one and assign the [EmployeeNo,EmpName,Commission] 
'to the dataset DtEmployee in which Employee is the table and EmpNo, EmpName, Commission 'are the coloumns.. 
Next 
End If
```

Please help me on this..

Comment: I Assigned some values to some variables by reading from excel. Now i need to assign those values one by one to datatable. so on that case i need an help to fill row by row on the table by reading the values. then the complete table should be saved to database

Comment: put your code that having problem to save data to DataTable..

Answer (score 2):

Try this to dump whole sheet to DataTable:

```
var connectionString = " Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";"
        var sheetName = "Sheet1";

        using (var con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            var table = new DataTable(sheetName);
            var query = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
            adapter.Fill(table);
            return table;
        }
```

Edit:  As per updated question

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then 
For n As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1 
EmployeeNo = (dt.Rows(n)(0)) 
EmpName = (dt.Rows(n)(1)).ToString 
Commission = CDbl(dt.Rows(n)(2)) 
'I need to read one by one and assign the [EmployeeNo,EmpName,Commission] 
'to the dataset DtEmployee in which Employee is the table and EmpNo, EmpName, Commission 'are the coloumns.. 

Dim dataRow As DataRow = DtEmployee.Tables("Employee").AsEnumerable().Where(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("EmpNo") = EmployeeNo).SingleOrDefault()
If dataRow IsNot Nothing Then

//Set your DataRow
dataRow("EmpName") = EmpName 
dataRow("Commission ") = Commission
DtEmployee.AcceptChanges();
End If

Next 
End If
```

Find the Row from the DtEmployee table and update that one or if you want to add new rows then  do not find row, just create new row and set value and add to DtEmployee

```
DataRow dataRow  = DtEmployee.Tables("Employee").NewRow()
//Set your DataRow
 dataRow("EmpName") = EmpName 
 dataRow("Commission ") = Commission
DtEmployee.Tables("Employee").Rows.Add(dataRow)
```

Hope this help..

Comment: If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For n As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

                    EmployeeNo = (dt.Rows(n)(0))
                    EmpName = (dt.Rows(n)(1)).ToString
                    Commission = CDbl(dt.Rows(n)(2))

                   
   \\ I need to read one by one and assign the [EmployeeNo,EmpName,Commission] to the dataset DtEmployee in which 
      Employee is the table and EmpNo, EmpName, Commission are the coloumns.. 

                 

  Next
            End If

Comment: Glad it helped. Btw, if this answer fits you, please accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer - see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) for more information. it will encourage others to help you.

Comment: I know it's old but I can confirm it worked. Wish I could mark it as the answer though :(